# Drawing column separator line for examdesign

Tags: two-column, examdesign

I want to draw a line in order to separate columns of `examdesign`. Making the document `twocolumn` doesn't work even though the questions are in two column.

Is it possible to draw a tikz picture as column separator? (Tikzpic would allow me to draw funny things)

Here is an `examdesign` sample (Taken from this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252961/examdesign-spacing-in-two-column)):

```
\documentclass[twocolumns]{examdesign} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\NoRearrange
\NoKey 
\ContinuousNumbering

\class{Class Name}
\examname{Exam Name}
\def\namedata{Name: \hrulefill \\[4pt] Block: \hrulefill \, Date: \hrulefill}

\parindent 0ex
\begin{document}

\begin{multiplechoice}[title={Multiple-Choice}, examcolumns=2]
Directions

  \begin{question}
    Question
    \choice{1}
    \choice{2}
    \choice[!]{3}
    \choice{4}
  \end{question}

  \begin{question}
    Question
    \choice{1}
    \choice{2}
    \choice[!]{3}
    \choice{4}
  \end{question}

  \begin{question}
    Question
    \choice{1}
    \choice{2}
    \choice[!]{3}
    \choice{4}
  \end{question}

\begin{question}
\lipsum[4]
  I. Statement I \\[0.5em]  
  II. Statement2 \\[0.5em]  
  III. Statement3 \\
    \choice{I only}
    \choice{II only}
    \choice{III only}
    \choice[!]{I, II, and III}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Question
    \choice{1}
    \choice{2}
    \choice[!]{3}
    \choice{4}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
\lipsum[4]
  I. Statement I \\[0.5em]  
  II. Statement2 \\[0.5em]  
  III. Statement3 \\
    \choice{I only}
    \choice{II only}
    \choice{III only}
    \choice[!]{I, II, and III}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Question
    \choice{1}
    \choice{2}
    \choice[!]{3}
    \choice{4}
\end{question}

\end{multiplechoice}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the `tikzpicture` outside the `multiple choice` environment causes a new page.  One could also use the `everypage` package.

Locating the bottom of the columns (rather than the text area) is difficult but possible.  Remember to run this twice.

```
\documentclass[twocolumns]{examdesign} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\NoRearrange
\NoKey 
\ContinuousNumbering

\class{Class Name}
\examname{Exam Name}
\def\namedata{Name: \hrulefill \\[4pt] Block: \hrulefill \, Date: \hrulefill}

\parindent 0ex
\begin{document}

\begin{multiplechoice}[title={Multiple-Choice}, examcolumns=2]

Directions
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate (here) at (0,-\baselineskip);
\draw[red] (current page text area.south) -- (current page text area.north |- here);
\end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{question}
    Question
    \choice{1}
    \choice{2}
    \choice[!]{3}
    \choice{4}
  \end{question}

  \begin{question}
    Question
    \choice{1}
    \choice{2}
    \choice[!]{3}
    \choice{4}
  \end{question}

  \begin{question}
    Question
    \choice{1}
    \choice{2}
    \choice[!]{3}
    \choice{4}
  \end{question}

\begin{question}
\lipsum[4]
  I. Statement I \\[0.5em]  
  II. Statement2 \\[0.5em]  
  III. Statement3 \\
    \choice{I only}
    \choice{II only}
    \choice{III only}
    \choice[!]{I, II, and III}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Question
    \choice{1}
    \choice{2}
    \choice[!]{3}
    \choice{4}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
\lipsum[4]
  I. Statement I \\[0.5em]  
  II. Statement2 \\[0.5em]  
  III. Statement3 \\
    \choice{I only}
    \choice{II only}
    \choice{III only}
    \choice[!]{I, II, and III}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Question
    \choice{1}
    \choice{2}
    \choice[!]{3}
    \choice{4}
\end{question}

\end{multiplechoice}

\end{document}
```